# Plugin jquey no funciona al cargar datos con ajax y php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

Necesito algo de ayuda. He buscado muchas preguntas y respuestas aquí, y nada.

Estoy intentando usar el plugin de jquery **mThumbnailScroller** para mostrar un *scrolling* horizontal de una lista de documentos, pero el plugin no funciona cuando cargo los datos con ajax y php desde la bd. Qué estoy haciendo mal? Dónde debo inicializar el plugin?

Mi index.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mThumbnailScroller.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrap-docs">
        <div id="scroll-docs" class="content-docs">
            <ul id="document-list"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    


    <script src="../plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.mThumbnailScroller.js"></script>
    <script>
        var item_doc = 0, obj;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax ({
                url: "fetch.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: {documents: "true"}
              }).done(function (data) {
                obj = data;
                item_doc = obj[0].nro;

                (function($){ //this doesn't work
                    $("#wrap-docs").load(function(){
                        $("#scroll-docs").mThumbnailScroller({
                            type:"click-25",
                        });
                    });
                })(jQuery); 

                descargas(); // no problem here, load data perfectly
                if (item_doc < 4) {
                  $("#mTS_1_buttonRight").hide();
                  $("#mTS_1_buttonLeft").hide();
                }
                else {
                  $("#mTS_1_buttonRight").show();
                  $("#mTS_1_buttonLeft").show();
                }
              });
              

            function descargas () {
                for (var i = 1; i <= item_doc; i++) {
                  document.getElementById('document-list').innerHTML += '<li>'
                  + '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">'
                  + '<div class="card card-list hoverable">'
                  + '<div id = "image-doc'+i+'" class="card-image waves-effect waves-light">'
                  + '</div>'
                  + '<div class="card-content">'
                  + '<span class="card-title col-grey">' + obj[i].titulo 
                  + '</span>'
                  + '<p>'
                  + '<a href="../sources/' + obj[i].contenido + '" download class="btn-flat-docs waves-effect waves-light">Descargar</a>'
                  + '</p>'
                  + '</div>'
                  + '</div>'
                  + '</div>'
                  + '</li>';
                }
              }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y así debería verse:
[image: Como debería verse el scrolling]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. La primera pregunta es ¿cómo sabes que es fallo del plugin y no del PHP? ¿Compruebas si se hace la llamada al PHP y el tipo de datos devuelto?¿Te sale algún mensaje de error en la consola JS?

Comment: Gracias. Si he comprobado que se hace la llamada al php y eso; no creo que sea falló del PHP  ya que los datos se muestra bien en cada card, pero sin el scrolling horizontal ni las clases e ids que añade el plugin. Antes cuando inicializaba el plugin fuera de la función ajax me salía este error en la consola: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". Pero de lo que leí por ahí, recomendaban situar  algún plugin jquery una vez los datos hayan sido cargados. Pero sigue sin funcionar aún.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo había publicado, pero ya he podido resolver el problema del plugin. Como es normal, el plugin debía llamarse una vez cargados los datos, entonces sólo moví las líneas de código del llamado del plugin dentro de la función descargas() donde son cargados los datos. Así ha quedado mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mThumbnailScroller.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrap-docs">
        <div id="scroll-docs" class="content-docs">
            <ul id="document-list"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    


    <script src="../plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.mThumbnailScroller.js"></script>
    <script>
        var item_doc = 0, obj;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax ({
                url: "fetch.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: {documents: "true"}
              }).done(function (data) {
                obj = data;
                item_doc = obj[0].nro;

                descargas();
                if (item_doc < 4) {
                  $("#mTS_1_buttonRight").hide();
                  $("#mTS_1_buttonLeft").hide();
                }
                else {
                  $("#mTS_1_buttonRight").show();
                  $("#mTS_1_buttonLeft").show();
                }
              });
              

            function descargas () {
                for (var i = 1; i <= item_doc; i++) {
                  document.getElementById('document-list').innerHTML += '<li>'
                  + '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">'
                  + '<div class="card card-list hoverable">'
                  + '<div id = "image-doc'+i+'" class="card-image waves-effect waves-light">'
                  + '</div>'
                  + '<div class="card-content">'
                  + '<span class="card-title col-grey">' + obj[i].titulo 
                  + '</span>'
                  + '<p>'
                  + '<a href="../sources/' + obj[i].contenido + '" download class="btn-flat-docs waves-effect waves-light">Descargar</a>'
                  + '</p>'
                  + '</div>'
                  + '</div>'
                  + '</div>'
                  + '</li>';
                }
               $("#scroll-docs").mThumbnailScroller({ //Aquí he hecho el llamado al plugin
                   type :"click-25",
                        });
              }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```